# How to add a key to a networkD3 visualization

Tags: r, d3.js, networkd3

Is there a way to add a key to a graph created using the networkD3 package in R? My graph was created using:

```
g1 <- simpleNetwork(df) ; htmltools::html_print(g1, viewer = utils::browseURL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what your need is.  But if you can use forceNetwork() instead of simpleNetwork() (from the same package), it has a legend = argument.  The data structure will need a bit of conversion - you need to define the nodes in one dataframe and the links/edges in another.  The links need to be numbers that relate to the rows in the nodes data frame, starting at zero.

Comment: Hi Peter, do you mind taking a look at a related networkD3 question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280218/r-networkd3-package-node-coloring-in-simplenetwork