# R networkD3 package: node coloring in simpleNetwork()

Tags: javascript, r, htmlwidgets, networkd3

The `networkD3` package (see [here](https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/) and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/networkD3/networkD3.pdf)) allows a user to create simple interactive networks:

```
# Load package
library(networkD3)

# Create fake data
src <- c("A", "A", "A", "A",
        "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
target <- c("B", "C", "D", "J",
            "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
networkData <- data.frame(src, target)

# Plot
simpleNetwork(networkData)
```

Is there a way to specify that I want all elements in the `src` vector to be a certain color, while allowing all the elements in the `target` vector to be a different color?  This would allow me to visually distinguish `src` nodes from `target` nodes in the network.

This functionality doesn't seem to be currently supported in `simpleNetwork()` (but I'm hoping somebody could help me out with a homebrew script):

[image]

A similar but not related question was [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480814).

Comment: Is it ok to use `forceNetwork()`, in the same package?  you can control colour through Group, and a JavaScript scale.  I can do a full answer if you're keen.

Comment: @PeterEllis Yes, that would be very helpful.

Comment: possibly a related question whereby one must colour the nodes with pre designated colours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793947/r-colouring-scheme-in-networkd3-vs-igraph?noredirect=1#comment65115769_38793947

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's how to control colour of nodes with `forceNetwork`.  Notice this still won't tell you the direction of the links because some nodes are source for some links and target for others - so you'll need to rethink that logic somehow.  But anyway, here's controlling colour of nodes.

```
# Load package
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr) # to make the joins easier

# Create fake data
src <- c("A", "A", "A", "A",
         "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
target <- c("B", "C", "D", "J",
            "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
networkData <- data.frame(src, target, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(src, target)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
nodes$id <- 0:(nrow(nodes) - 1)


# create a data frame of the edges that uses id 0:9 instead of their names
edges <- networkData %>%
   left_join(nodes, by = c("src" = "name")) %>%
   select(-src) %>%
   rename(source = id) %>%
   left_join(nodes, by = c("target" = "name")) %>%
   select(-target) %>%
   rename(target = id)

edges$width <- 1

# make a grouping variable that will match to colours
nodes$group <- ifelse(nodes$name %in% src, "lions", "tigers")

# simple with default colours
forceNetwork(Links = edges, Nodes = nodes, 
             Source = "source",
             Target = "target",
             NodeID ="name",
             Group = "group",
             Value = "width",
             opacity = 0.9,
             zoom = TRUE)

# control colours with a JS ordinal scale
# edited 20 May 2017 with updated code from Renal Chesak's answer:
ColourScale <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(["lions", "tigers"])
           .range(["#FF6900", "#694489"]);'

forceNetwork(Links = edges, Nodes = nodes, 
             Source = "source",
             Target = "target",
             NodeID ="name",
             Group = "group",
             Value = "width",
             opacity = 0.9,
             zoom = TRUE,
             colourScale = JS(ColourScale))
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to have the nodes all labeled.  Could you please expand your answer to show how to make the nodes (for both `src` and `target`) have their names be automatically displayed instead of on-hover accessibility only?

Comment: There is an argument called `opacityNoHover` for this. Use `opacityNoHover = 1` to always show the node labels.

Answer (score 5):

Peter Ellis's answer above might have worked at one time, but it seems the code has been updated in a new release. Instead of `d3.scale.ordinal().range([])`, you will have to use `d3.scaleOrdinal().range([])`

Comment: Thanks.  I don't use this combination very often and only saw the change three years after your answer here, when wondering in my own work why this doesn't work any more!  I've edited my original answer in response.

Answer (score 2):

Peter Ellis' answer does the job, but this is an alternate approach, which imho is bit more concise and easier to understand...

(Also, it should be noted that nodes can be in both the `source` and the `target` vectors at the same time, in which case, which color they should be, given your specification, is uncertain.)

```
library(networkD3)

src <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
target <- c("B", "C", "D", "J", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
networkData <- data.frame(src, target, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# make a nodes data frame out of all unique nodes in networkData
nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(networkData$src, networkData$target)))

# make a group variable where nodes in networkData$src are identified
nodes$group <- nodes$name %in% networkData$src

# make a links data frame using the indexes (0-based) of nodes in 'nodes'
links <- data.frame(source = match(networkData$src, nodes$name) - 1,
                    target = match(networkData$target, nodes$name) - 1)

forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source",
             Target = "target", NodeID ="name", Group = "group",
             opacity = 1, opacityNoHover = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do a similar thing as in the linked post, but here is an example using the `visNetwork` package.  This package interfaces with vis.js, and makes really nice interactive graphs.

```
library(visNetwork)
id <- unique(c(src, target))                                  # node ids
nodes <- data.frame(id, group=+(id %in% src),                 # add a grouping for src/target
  label=id, title=sprintf('<p>Node %s</p>', id))              # add some labels
g <- visNetwork(nodes=nodes, edges=networkData, width="75%")  # make graph
visExport(visHierarchicalLayout(g))                           # make it tree-like
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool.  I sure hope you find something similar in `networkD3` :-) +1