# R networkD3 package: forceNetwork() coloring

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, networkd3

I really like how this network looks:

[image]

Source: https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/

There are multiple colors for each sector, where each color represents some distinct portion of nodes in the network that are far enough separated from the other nodes.

However, within any one specific sector, I don't like how the `src` nodes are the same color as the `target` nodes, and so I asked a question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371131/3878253) for how to distinguish the two colors.

Now is there a way that I can expand on this code to get the multiple color scheme back (to distinguish the various sectors from each other) yet retain the nice `src`/`target` difference in color?  Here is the code:

```
# Load package
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr) # to make the joins easier

# Create fake data
src <- c("A", "A", "A", "A",
         "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
target <- c("B", "C", "D", "J",
            "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
networkData <- data.frame(src, target, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(src, target)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
nodes$id <- 0:(nrow(nodes) - 1)


# create a data frame of the edges that uses id 0:9 instead of their names
edges <- networkData %>%
   left_join(nodes, by = c("src" = "name")) %>%
   select(-src) %>%
   rename(source = id) %>%
   left_join(nodes, by = c("target" = "name")) %>%
   select(-target) %>%
   rename(target = id)

edges$width <- 1

# make a grouping variable that will match to colours
nodes$group <- ifelse(nodes$name %in% src, "lions", "tigers")


ColourScale <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(["lions", "tigers"])
           .range(["#FF6900", "#694489"]);'

forceNetwork(Links = edges, Nodes = nodes, 
             Source = "source",
             Target = "target",
             NodeID ="name",
             Group = "group",
             Value = "width",
             opacity = 0.9,
             zoom = TRUE,
             colourScale = JS(ColourScale))
```

Answer (score 2):

After re-reading your question and response, I think what you really want to know is... how to cluster your data into groups. Once you've defined the clusters, you can set the group value for each node in the `nodes` data frame as the name/id of its cluster, and then `networkD3` will color them accordingly.

Further into your question, it's not exactly clear how you want to combine 'color source and target nodes differently' **and** 'color nodes according to their cluster' simultaneously... those goals obviously conflict because clusters contain both source and target nodes. An additional problem with your question is that in these types of networks, it's possible for a node to be both a source and a target node, so you would have to be more clear about how you want those to be colored. I could make an assumption that you define a 'target' node as one that is only linked to one other node (technically, whether a node is a source or a target is determined by the direction of the link between nodes), but that's not necessarily the case (I can imagine other interpretations you might have).

To do the clustering, you want to look into the `igraph` package and its numerous clustering functions. for example...

using the Les Misérables data included in the `networkD3`, let's backtrack till we have just a two column data frame with source and target characters...

```
library(igraph)
library(networkD3)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

lesmis <- data.frame(source = MisNodes$name[MisLinks$source + 1], 
                     target = MisNodes$name[MisLinks$target + 1],
                     stringsAsFactors = F)
```

now, using that you can use `igraph` to calculate the clusters, and then put them back together to plot in `networkD3`...

```
lesmis <- graph_from_data_frame(lesmis)
wc <- cluster_walktrap(lesmis)
members <- membership(wc)

lesmis <- igraph_to_networkD3(lesmis, group = members)

forceNetwork(Links = lesmis$links, Nodes = lesmis$nodes, 
             Source = 'source', Target = 'target', 
             NodeID = 'name', Group = 'group', opacity = 1)
```

now if you want to make 'target' nodes (those that have only one link) a different color also, you could figure out which nodes only appear once in the list of sources and targets, and set their group value in the `nodes` data frame to something unique...

```
allnodes <- c(lesmis$links$source, lesmis$links$target)
targetids <- allnodes[!duplicated(allnodes) & ! duplicated(allnodes, fromLast = T)]
lesmis$nodes$group[targetids + 1] <- 'target'

forceNetwork(Links = lesmis$links, Nodes = lesmis$nodes, 
             Source = 'source', Target = 'target', 
             NodeID = 'name', Group = 'group', opacity = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `group` column in the `Nodes` data frame is what determines the color. You can set the `group` value for each node (manually or otherwise), and `networkD3` will color each group of nodes according to a palette of colors.

For instance...

```
edges <- read.table(header = T, text = '
source target width
0      1     1
0      2     1
0      3     1
0      4     1
1      5     1
1      6     1
2      7     1
2      8     1
3      9     1
')

nodes <- read.table(header = T, text = '
name id  group
A    0   panther
B    1   leopard
C    2   tiger
D    3   lion
J    4   panthercub
E    5   leopardcub
F    6   leopardcub
G    7   tigercub
H    8   tigercub
I    9   lioncub
')

forceNetwork(Links = edges, Nodes = nodes, 
             Source = "source",
             Target = "target",
             NodeID ="name",
             Group = "group",
             Value = "width",
             opacity = 0.9,
             zoom = TRUE,
             colourScale = JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);"))
```

Comment: As you mentioned, this solution requires manually setting values in the `group` column of the `nodes` data frame.  However, I'm asking if there's a way to automate this process, by letting the source code do the coloring of the various sectors of the network for you automatically.  In larger networks, this would be a big plus (i.e., it would be very nice and scalable).  I like your answer though, as it shows where the concept of coloring comes from in the first place.

Comment: You can preprocess the nodes data frame to set the group values in whatever way you want. If you give a specific use case, I might be able to help you do that, but there are near infinite possibilities without knowing specifics.