# Sankey network manual colour change

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I am trying to build sankey plot using *networkD3* library. I have following code and data:

```
# Plotting the Sankey network diagram
nodes = data.frame("name" = 
                     c("Mamalian", # Node 0
                       "Avian", # Node 1
                       "Critical", # Node 2
                       "Critical-maintained", # Node 3
                       "Endangerd", #Node 4
                       "Endangered-maintained", #Node 5
                       "Not at risk")) # Node 6

links = as.data.frame(matrix(c(
  0, 2, 16, # Note the values in the final column refer to the % of breeds in each risk category
  0, 3, 2.2, 
  0, 4, 17.6, 
  0, 5, 7.0,
  0, 6, 57.2,
  1, 2, 23.9, 
  1, 3, 1.3, 
  1, 4, 24.7, 
  1, 5, 13.1,
  1, 6, 37.0),
  byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))
names(links) = c("source", "target", "value")
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              fontSize= 12, nodeWidth = 30, iterations = 0)
```

I want to manually change the colours associated with each node, as they ddo not currently correspond with the endangerment categories I have listed. How can I do this?

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371131/680068), you can define  a "group" for nodes dataframe, then each node will be assigned some colour per grouping. But can't see how we can set custom colours, maybe using `colourScale`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `colourScale` parameter to set a custom JS/D3 color scale. (I replaced spaces in your names with `-` because `d3.scaleOrdinal()` doesn't like them). Using your data/objects from your example....

```
nodes$group <- gsub(" ", "-", nodes$name)

color_scale <- 
  "d3.scaleOrdinal()
     .domain(['Mamalian', 'Avian', 'Critical', 'Critical-maintained', 
              'Endangerd', 'Endangered-maintained', 'Not-at-risk'])
     .range(['#000', '#F00', '#0F0', '#00F', '#FF0', '#F0F', '#0FF']);
  "
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "name", 
              fontSize= 12, nodeWidth = 30, iterations = 0,
              NodeGroup = "group", colourScale = color_scale)
```

Comment: CJ Yetman, thank you so much. All of your answers regarding Sankey- diagram is helping me a lot.